# Issue on Magento Feefo Integration

Tags: magento, integration

I had integrated Flint FEEFO with magento, I'm getting flint feefo option in system >> configuration >> sales >> flint feefo

in user side im getting broken image icon, on clicking that icon im getting this [feefo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBpBn.jpg)

please help im new to magento.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: oh sorry i will post this question there..thanks for the info...